# Pixelated image in Fabric.js with sliceHack Resize filter

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I can't find a way to use the Resize filter (slideHack) without getting a pixelated image sometimes.
I use fabric.js 1.7.2

[image]

1. I just added the image in the canvas

   ```
   fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) 
   {
       var scaling = 0.2;
       var rFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
           resizeType: 'sliceHack'
       });
       oImg.resizeFilters.push(rFilter);
       oImg.applyFilters();

       oImg.set({
           left:   300, 
           top:    300, 
           scaleX: scaling, 
           scaleY: scaling
       });

       canvas.add(oImg);
       canvas.renderAll();
   });
   ```
2. When I click on the image or resize it manually, the edges get smooth.
3. When I apply a Tint Filter, it is pixelated again

I can't find the function triggered to smooth the edges...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in the step 3, if you apply a resize filter, it is ok ?

Comment: There is already an applyFilters() call because I pushed a Tint (white) filter. If I push again a resize filter a second time the image gets blurry. To get the white edges smooth, I have to resize the image in the UI (strange).

Comment: Can you send a jsfiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document [Introduction to Fabric.js, Part 2](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2) suggests the following syntax, which seems to solve the issue:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('pug.jpg', function(img) {

  // add filter
  img.filters.push(filter);

  // apply filters and re-render canvas when done
  img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

  // add image onto canvas
  canvas.add(img);
});
```

The result is compared to your original method in the code snippet below. In order to make it work, I also added `{ crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' }` (see the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34872442/1009922) by AndreaBogazzi).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var url = 'http://i.imgur.com/a47Yxsb.png';
var imgWidth = 770;

function performScaling() {
  // Get scaling factor
  var scaling =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtScaling").value);

  canvas.clear();

  // With original method
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) 
  {
    var rFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
      resizeType: 'sliceHack'
    });
    oImg.resizeFilters.push(rFilter);
    oImg.applyFilters();

    oImg.set({
      left:   0, 
      top:    16, 
      scaleX: scaling, 
      scaleY: scaling
    });

    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  // As suggested in Fabric.js introduction
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (oImg) {
      oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
          resizeType: 'sliceHack', scaleX: scaling , scaleY: scaling 
      }));
    oImg.set({
      left: imgWidth * 1.1 * scaling,
      top: 16
    });
    oImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));  
    canvas.add(oImg);
  },{ crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' });
  
  // Add labels
  canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Pixelated', {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontSize: 12,
    left: 0.48 * imgWidth * scaling,
    top: 0,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center'
  }));  
  
  canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Not pixelated', {
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontSize: 12,
    left: 1.58 * imgWidth * scaling,
    top: 0,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center'
  }));  
}
```

```css
#divScaling
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 6px 32px 16px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#txtScaling
{
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="divScaling">
  <label for="txtScaling">Scaling factor: </label>
  <input id="txtScaling" type="text" value="0.2" />
  <button onclick="performScaling()">
  Scale
  </button>
</div>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/a47Yxsb.png" style="width: 30px;height: 30px;"/>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: `fabric.Image.fromURL` is not alway an option, because it's slower than `fabric.Image`.

I hope someone can point to a better solution

Answer (score 1):

I think that pixelated problem was fixed in version 2. Edge was smoother than version 1.72

Notice breaking changes in v2:

> Another breaking change is that the .resizeFilters is no more an array of resize filter. Is a single resizeFilter that you can use when the object is scaled on the canvas.
>
> image.resizeFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.ResizeFilter({type: 'hermite'});

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var url = 'http://i.imgur.com/a47Yxsb.png';
var imgWidth = 1024;

function performScaling() {
  // Get scaling factor
  var scaling =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtScaling").value);

  canvas.clear();

  // As suggested in Fabric.js introduction
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (oImg) {
    oImg.set({
      left: imgWidth * 1.1 * scaling,
      top: 16
    });
    oImg.scale(scaling);
    oImg.resizeFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
        resizeType: 'sliceHack'
    });
    oImg.applyResizeFilters();
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();

    // canvas.setBackgroundImage(
    //   oImg,
    //   () => {
    //     canvas.renderAll();
    //   },
    // );
    
  },{ crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' });
  
  // Add labels
  
  canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Not pixelated', {
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontSize: 12,
    left: 1.58 * imgWidth * scaling,
    top: 0,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center'
  }));  
}
```

```css
#divScaling
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 6px 32px 16px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#txtScaling
{
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="divScaling">
  <label for="txtScaling">Scaling factor: </label>
  <input id="txtScaling" type="text" value="0.2" />
  <button onclick="performScaling()">
  Scale
  </button>
</div>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/a47Yxsb.png" style="width: 30px;height: 30px;"/>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```